# Printing from Android doesn't send the chosen size (Brother QL-7000)

Tags: printers, google-cloud-print, android-print-framework

We shared a Brother QL-700 over Google cloud print.

We print from a desktop the print went through without an issue.

But, when we print from an android no matter which page size we pick it gets to the printer as 3.5' which doesn't fit the printer.

We tried from different apps (google docs, word..) and nothing helped same issue everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging and many support calls with Brother we found the issue as a driver bug (Brother released a fix), which caused GPC to wrongly read the printer configuration.